# Finding ALL duplicate rows, including "elements with smaller subscripts"

Tags: r, duplicates, r-faq

R's `duplicated` returns a vector showing whether each element of a vector or data frame is a duplicate of an element with a smaller subscript. So if rows 3, 4, and 5 of a 5-row data frame are the same, `duplicated` will give me the vector

```
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
```

But in this case I actually want to get

```
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
```

that is, I want to know whether a row is duplicated by a row with a **larger** subscript too.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`duplicated` has a `fromLast` argument.  The "Example" section of `?duplicated` shows you how to use it.  Just call `duplicated` twice, once with `fromLast=FALSE` and once with `fromLast=TRUE` and take the rows where either are `TRUE`.

---

Some late Edit: 
You didn't provide a reproducible example, so here's an illustration kindly contributed by @jbaums

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c","c","c") 
vec[duplicated(vec) | duplicated(vec, fromLast=TRUE)]
## [1] "c" "c" "c"
```

---

Edit: And an example for the case of a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(rbind(c("a","a"),c("b","b"),c("c","c"),c("c","c")))
df[duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast=TRUE), ]
##   X1 X2
## 3  c  c
## 4  c  c
```

Comment: Hold on, I just ran a test and found I was wrong:
`x <- c(1:9, 7:10, 5:22);
y <- c(letters, letters[1:5]);
test <- data.frame(x, y);
test[duplicated(test$x) | duplicated(test$x, fromLast=TRUE), ]`
Returned all three of he copies of 7, 8, and 9. Why does that work?

Comment: Because the middle ones are captured no matter if you start from the end or from the front. For example, `duplicated(c(1,1,1))` vs `duplicated(c(1,1,1,), fromLast = TRUE)` gives `c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)` and `c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)`. Middle value is `TRUE` in both cases. Taking `|` of both vectors gives `c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)`.

Answer (score 43):

You need to assemble the set of `duplicated` values, apply `unique`, and then test with `%in%`. As always, a sample problem will make this process come alive.

```
> vec <- c("a", "b", "c","c","c")
> vec[ duplicated(vec)]
[1] "c" "c"
> unique(vec[ duplicated(vec)])
[1] "c"
>  vec %in% unique(vec[ duplicated(vec)]) 
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Agree. Might even slow down processing but unlikely to slow it down very much.

Comment: Quite true. The OP did not offer a data example to test for "ever duplicated" rows in a dataframe. I think my suggestion of using `duplicated`, `unique` and `%in%` could easily be generalized to a dataframe if one were to first `paste` each row with an unusual separator character. (The accepted answer is better.)

Answer (score 25):

Duplicated rows in a dataframe could be obtained with `dplyr` by doing

```
library(tidyverse)
df = bind_rows(iris, head(iris, 20)) # build some test data
df %>% group_by_all() %>% filter(n()>1) %>% ungroup()
```

To exclude certain columns `group_by_at(vars(-var1, -var2))` could be used instead to group the data.

If the row indices and not just the data is actually needed, you could add them first as in:

```
df %>% add_rownames %>% group_by_at(vars(-rowname)) %>% filter(n()>1) %>% pull(rowname)
```

Comment: Nice use of `n()`. Don't forget to ungroup the resulting dataframe.

Comment: @qwr I've adjusted the answer to ungroup the result

Comment: @HolgerBrandl, @qwr, The general answer is useful, but I don't understand how to pick column(s) to exclude.  What is the "vars" refer to in `group_by_at(vars(-var1, -var2))`?  Are `var1` and `var2` column names in a datatable named `vars`?  I assume the negative signs signify exclusion, right?  So the rest of the process (`filter` and `ungroup`) acts on the rest of the columns in that datatable `vars`, but not including `var1` and `var2` is that right?  Sorry to be so pedantic, but I often have problems with quick shorthand!

Comment: `vars` is a method in dplyr, see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/vars.html . var1, var2 indeed refer to column names to be excluded from the duplication check. Duplication is assessed on the grouping variables in the suggested solution. Indeed, negative signifies exclusion.

Comment: `group_by_all()` and `group_by_at()` have been superseded in recent versions of dplyr.  Now you can do this:                
`iris %>% group_by(across()) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup()`

Answer (score 6):

Here is @Joshua Ulrich's solution as a function. This format allows you to use this code in the same fashion that you would use duplicated():

```
allDuplicated <- function(vec){
  front <- duplicated(vec)
  back <- duplicated(vec, fromLast = TRUE)
  all_dup <- front + back > 0
  return(all_dup)
}
```

Using the same example:

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "c","c","c") 
allDuplicated(vec) 
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how `vctrs::vec_duplicate_detect()` works

```r
# on a vector
vctrs::vec_duplicate_detect(c(1, 2, 1))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
# on a data frame
vctrs::vec_duplicate_detect(mtcars[c(1, 2, 1),])
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I've had the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571154/get-rows-where-one-value-is-duplicated?noredirect=1#comment62629882_37571154), and if I'm not mistaken, this is also an answer.

```
vec[col %in% vec[duplicated(vec$col),]$col]
```

Dunno which one is faster, though, the dataset I'm currently using isn't big enough to make tests which produce significant time gaps.

Comment: This answer seems to use `vec` both as an atomic vector and as a dataframe. I suspect that with an actual datframe it would fail.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem but I needed to identify duplicated rows by values in specific columns. I came up with the following **dplyr** solution:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Column1, Column2, Column3) %>% 
  mutate(Duplicated = case_when(length(Column1)>1 ~ "Yes",
                            TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The code groups the rows by specific columns. If the length of a group is greater than 1 the code marks all of the rows in the group as duplicated. Once that is done you can use `Duplicated` column for filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in which rows are duplicated for certain columns you can use a **plyr** approach:

```
ddply(df, .(col1, col2), function(df) if(nrow(df) > 1) df else c())
```

Adding a count variable with **dplyr**:

```
df %>% add_count(col1, col2) %>% filter(n > 1)  # data frame
df %>% add_count(col1, col2) %>% select(n) > 1  # logical vector
```

For duplicate rows (considering all columns):

```
df %>% group_by_all %>% add_tally %>% ungroup %>% filter(n > 1)
df %>% group_by_all %>% add_tally %>% ungroup %>% select(n) > 1
```

The benefit of these approaches is that you can specify how many duplicates as a cutoff.

Answer (score 0):

This updates @Holger Brandl's answer to reflect recent versions of dplyr (e.g. 1.0.5), in which `group_by_all()` and `group_by_at()` have been superseded.  The help doc suggests using `across()` instead.

Thus, to get all rows for which there is a duplicate you can do this:
`iris %>% group_by(across()) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup()`

To include the indices of such rows, add a 'rowid' column but exclude it from the grouping:
`iris %>% rowid_to_column() %>% group_by(across(!rowid)) %>% filter(n() > 1) %>% ungroup()`

Append `%>% pull(rowid)` after the above and you'll get a vector of the indices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new column which lists "TRUE" for any row where the value "id" is duplicated, it took me awhile to figure this out:

`data %>% mutate(duplicate_id = if_else(id %in% id[duplicated(id), TRUE, FALSE))`