# Does R duplicated function only identify entries that are doubled?

Tags: r

I have a table with ~14000 entries. I want to identify entries that have multiple copies (i.e. 2+). I tried the duplicated function and sure enough, I got 55 entries that were duplicated (2x). However, I suspect that there could be entries with 3+.

At this point, is there a function that can address this, or should I write my own method (i.e. with factors)?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it finds all duplicates. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7854433/271616) and note the `fromLast` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is finding the values that have more than 1 copy in your vector/table, then something like this would work:

```
x <- sample(1:10, 20, replace=TRUE)
as.integer(names(which(table(x) > 1)))
```

If however, you want to find the indexes/positions of the 2nd, 3rd, etcetera occurrences, then  `duplicated()` does the trick (also for 3+).

```
sel <- which(duplicated(x))
x[sel]
```

However, do note that `duplicated()` does not tag the 1st occurrence as a duplicate; this may cause some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The `duplicated` function simply gives you a logical vector telling you which entries are duplicates of previous entries and which entries are not duplicates. In that sense, it does *not* merely identify elements which are doubled, but instead gives you information about *all* elements for which there are more than one copy.

```
> a = c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5)
> duplicated(a)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you want to know exactly which values are duplicated, you can take all elements for which `duplicated` returns `TRUE` and then `unique` them.

```
unique(a[duplicated(a)])
```