# Separate duplicates of a data.frame into another data.frame

Tags: r, dataset

I have a data.frame `x`, from which I want to put all duplicated rows in a new data frame `z`. My data frame looks like this:

```
1 A
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
4 D
```

At the moment I use `z <- x[duplicated(x$column_name),]`, which gives me:

```
1 A
4 D
```

but what I want is:

```
1 A
1 A
4 D
4 D
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: This is question would be better on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854620/6229919) provides one possible solution to this problem: compute `duplicated` twice with `fromLast=T` enabled once:

```
> d <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,2,3,4,4), y=c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'))
> d[c(duplicated(d) | duplicated(d, fromLast = T)),]

  X1 X2
1  1  A
2  1  A
5  4  D
6  4  D
```