# How to refer to multiple column names held in a variable inside a function

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

This follows from [Extract rows with duplicate values in two or more fields but different values in another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45652340/extract-rows-with-duplicate-values-in-two-or-more-fields-but-different-values-in)

As suggested, I'm posting additional request separately. First code then question.

```
library(data.table)

# load the data
customers <- structure(list(
  NAME = c("B V RAMANA  ", "K KRISHNA", "B SUDARSHAN", "B ANNAPURNA ",
           "BIKASH BAHADUR CHITRE", "KOTLA CHENNAMMA ", "K KRISHNA",
           "  B V RAMANA", "B ANNAPURNA", "ZAITOON BEE", "BIMAN BALAIAH",
           " KOTLA CHENNAMMA ", "B V RAMANA"),
  DOB = c("15-01-1960", "01-05-1964", "12-03-1975", "12-12-1962",
          "14-05-1983", "15-07-1958", "01-05-1964", "15-01-1960",
          "12-12-1962", "20-02-1960", "10-03-1964", "15-07-1958",
          "15-01-1960"), 
  ID = c(" 502910", "502737", "502995", " 502878", "502984",
         "502466", "502737", "502902 ", "502877 ", "503000",
         "502979", "502467", "502902 "),
  PIN = c(500033, 500050, 500032, 500084, 500032, 500032, 500084, 500035,
          500084, 500084, 500032, 500032, 500032)), 
  .Names = c("NAME", "DOB", "ID", "PIN"),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))

# function for Duplicate Key Exclusion
dupKeyEx <- function(DT, dup_cols, unique_cols) {
  cols <-  c(dup_cols, unique_cols)
  mDT <-  DT[!duplicated(DT, by=cols), .N, by=dup_cols][N > 1L]
  ans <- unique(DT[mDT[, !"N"], on=dup_cols], by=cols)
  setorderv(ans, c(dup_cols, unique_cols))
  return(ans)
}
```

Running the function gets zero results because of whitespaces in the beginning or end of `NAME` and `ID` columns in `customers` table:

```
dup_cols <- c("NAME", "DOB")
unique_cols <- "ID"
dupKeyEx(customers, dup_cols, unique_cols)
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 4 cols: NAME,DOB,ID,PIN
```

So we trim, ie, remove whitespaces from both ends of the relevant columns:

```
library(stringr)
customers[, `:=`(NAME = str_trim(NAME),
                 ID = str_trim(ID))]
```

Now we get the expected results:

```
dupKeyEx(customers, dup_cols, unique_cols)
              NAME        DOB     ID    PIN
1:     B ANNAPURNA 12-12-1962 502877 500084
2:     B ANNAPURNA 12-12-1962 502878 500084
3:      B V RAMANA 15-01-1960 502902 500035
4:      B V RAMANA 15-01-1960 502910 500033
5: KOTLA CHENNAMMA 15-07-1958 502466 500032
6: KOTLA CHENNAMMA 15-07-1958 502467 500032
```

I was wondering if the columns in `dup_cols` and `unique_cols` (together assigned in `cols` variable inside the `dupKeyEx` function) could be trimmed inside the function itself. That way, I won't need to remember to trim the relevant columns before using the `dupKeyEx` function.

I searched but was unable to find ways to refer to columns inside `cols` variable and apply `stringr::str_trim()` on them inside the `dupKeyEx` function. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
dupKeyEx <- function(DT, dup_cols, unique_cols) {
  sapply(dup_cols,function(x) DT[[x]] <<- str_trim(DT[[x]]))
  cols <-  c(dup_cols, unique_cols)
  mDT <-  DT[!duplicated(DT, by=cols), .N, by=dup_cols][N > 1L]
  ans <- unique(DT[mDT[, !"N"], on=dup_cols], by=cols)
  setorderv(ans, c(dup_cols, unique_cols))
  return(ans)
}
```

or follow @Frank's advice, using `data.table` syntax. We make a copy of the table first not to modify the input:

```
dupKeyEx <- function(DT, dup_cols, unique_cols) {
  DT<-copy(DT) # comment if you want to keep changes by reference
  DT[, (dup_cols) := lapply(.SD, str_trim), .SDcols=dup_cols]
  cols <-  c(dup_cols, unique_cols)
  mDT <-  DT[!duplicated(DT, by=cols), .N, by=dup_cols][N > 1L]
  ans <- unique(DT[mDT[, !"N"], on=dup_cols], by=cols)
  setorderv(ans, c(dup_cols, unique_cols))
  return(ans)
}
```

**Edit by San:** The following serves my purpose nicely:

```
dupKeyEx <- function(DT, dup_cols, unique_cols) {
  cols <-  c(dup_cols, unique_cols)
  chr_cols <- cols[sapply(DT[, ..cols], is.character)]
  DT[, (chr_cols) := lapply(.SD, stringr::str_trim), .SDcols=chr_cols]
  mDT <-  DT[!duplicated(DT, by=cols), .N, by=dup_cols][N > 1L]
  ans <- unique(DT[mDT[, !"N"], on=dup_cols], by=cols)
  setorderv(ans, c(dup_cols, unique_cols))
  return(ans)
}
```

Thanks to both contributors. I've modified code to apply `str_trim` only on character columns so as to avoid changing other column types to character. This change is made by reference because making copies of large tables costs resources including time. Also, trimming has no bad side effects in my analysis job - it is usually necessary.

Generally speaking, trimming all character columns should be done immediately after loading any large table by something like:

```
trimCharCols <- function(DT) {
  colsDT <- names(DT)
  chr_cols <- colsDT[sapply(DT, is.character)]
  DT[, (chr_cols) := lapply(.SD, stringr::str_trim), .SDcols=chr_cols]
}
```

in which case two lines of code from `dupKeyEx` function may be avoided. But I'm going to leave them there for the time being because I need this function to be "independent".

Comment: `<<-` is pretty exotic. More standard, maybe: `DT[, (dup_cols) := lapply(.SD, str_trim), .SDcols=dup_cols]`. I guess either way, it is modifying the input data by reference (?), which might be an undesirable (or at least unexpected) side-effect.

Comment: I don't know `data.table` well so I just gave something that worked, it might not be the best choice, but input data is not modified.

Comment: I know `<<-` should be used carefully, but in `sapply` I feel I'm safe enough and it's convenient, would you advise against it ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I would avoid it myself. I don't see gain vs a `for` loop and wouldn't want to get into bad habits or confusing code. Fwiw, the base R idiom is `DF[, dup_cols] <- lapply(DF[, dup_cols], str_trim)`, similar to the data.table one... I only use `<<-` in extraordinary cases.

Comment: @San you may prefer prefer @Frank's solution without the `copy`, the solution you propose seems to do the same with an extra `sapply`

Comment: Got it. The revised solution is perfect. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Frank: Can we avoid copying the whole table (reducing RAM needs), maybe copy just the criteria columns instead and yet get the same result without modifying table by reference?

Comment: @San Probably. But I think it'd be better to simply create `chrdupe_cols = dupe_cols[sapply(DT[, ..dupe_cols], is.character)]` inside the function and run the `str_trim` on only those if your concern is that some cols will be Date.

Comment: @Frank: your syntax works fine. But please tell me what the double period in `..dupe_cols` do. Any links for further explanation?

Comment: @San It's "experimental" at the moment and hasn't been formally documented. For now, this is the best reference: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2145

Comment: @Frank: Very useful info. Thanks. `data.table` is awesome. I wonder when we would get `margins` support for its `dcast` function like `reshape2` and a direct syntax for semi-join like `dplyr`.

Comment: @San may I ask why you don't clean your input from the start ? Cleaning it through the function and "getting advantage" of the changes by reference as you go doesn't seem very clean to me.

Comment: @Frank: You are right about cleaning input beforehand and I've updated the post regarding that. It is just that I need the `dupKeyEx` function to be "independent" of other table activities.

Comment: @San Re using the table without copying, there's the shallow function https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/617 It is not yet released / exported or feature-complete, I guess, but I have tried it in my own functions for work. Anyway, we could move any further discussion to the R chat room rather than pinging Moody here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public