# Pull subset of rows of dataframe based on conditions from other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, subset

I have a `dataframe` like the one below:

```
x <- data.table(Tickers=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D"),
                Type=c("put","call","put","call","call","put","call","put","call","put","call"),
                Strike=c(35,37.5,37.5,10,11,11,12,40,40,42,42),
                Other=sample(20,11))

    Tickers Type Strike Other
 1:       A  put   35.0     6
 2:       A call   37.5     5
 3:       A  put   37.5    13
 4:       B call   10.0    15
 5:       B call   11.0    12
 6:       B  put   11.0     4
 7:       B call   12.0    20
 8:       D  put   40.0     7
 9:       D call   40.0    11
10:       D  put   42.0    10
11:       D call   42.0     1
```

I am trying to analyze a subset of the data. The subset I would like to take is data where the `ticker` and `strike` are the same. But I also only want to grab this data if both a `put` and a `call` exists under `type`. With the data above for example, I would like to return the following result:

```
x[c(2,3,5,6,8:11),]

   Tickers Type Strike Other
1:       A call   37.5     5
2:       A  put   37.5    13
3:       B call   11.0    12
4:       B  put   11.0     4
5:       D  put   40.0     7
6:       D call   40.0    11
7:       D  put   42.0    10
8:       D call   42.0     1
```

I'm not sure what the best way to go about doing this. My thought process is that I should create another column vector like

```
x$id <- paste(x$Tickers,x$Strike,sep="_")
```

Then use this vector to only pull values where there are multiple ids.

```
x[x$id %in% x$id[duplicated(x$id)],]

   Tickers Type Strike Other     id
1:       A call   37.5     5 A_37.5
2:       A  put   37.5    13 A_37.5
3:       B call   11.0    12   B_11
4:       B  put   11.0     4   B_11
5:       D  put   40.0     7   D_40
6:       D call   40.0    11   D_40
7:       D  put   42.0    10   D_42
8:       D call   42.0     1   D_42
```

I'm not sure how efficient this is, as my actual data consists of a lot more rows.
Also, this solution does not check for the `type` condition of there being one `put` and one `call`.

also the wording of the title could be a lot better, I apologize

EDIT::: having checked out this post [Finding ALL duplicate rows, including "elements with smaller subscripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts)

I could also use this solution:

```
x$id <- paste(x$Tickers,x$Strike,sep="_")
x[duplicated(x$id) | duplicated(x$id,fromLast=T),]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
x[, select := (.N >= 2 & all(c("put", "call") %in% unique(Type))), by = .(Tickers, Strike)][which(select)]

#   Tickers Type Strike Other select
#1:       A call   37.5    17   TRUE
#2:       A  put   37.5    16   TRUE
#3:       B call   11.0    11   TRUE
#4:       B  put   11.0    20   TRUE
#5:       D  put   40.0     1   TRUE
#6:       D call   40.0    12   TRUE
#7:       D  put   42.0     6   TRUE
#8:       D call   42.0     2   TRUE
```

Another idea might be a merge:

```
x[x, on = .(Tickers, Strike), select := (length(Type) >= 2 & all(c("put", "call") %in% Type)),by = .EACHI][which(select)]
```

I'm not entirely sure how to get around the group-by operations since you want to make sure for each group they have both "call" and "put". I was thinking about using keys, but haven't been able to incorporate the "call"/"put" aspect.

Comment: I like this - the `all(c("put", "call") %in% unique(Type))` part is more robust than my solution.

Comment: Thanks @BrianStamper, it was inspired in part by your solution so thank you!

Comment: And the `which(select)` construct is one I am going to have to remember!

Comment: Very nice solution! I really appreciate the `all(c("put", "call") %in% unique(Type))` part as well. This allows for more complex subsetting if my `type` variable were to include other combinations of options. If I were to want to include another column as part of the group, I could also simply add it `by = .(Tickers, Strike)` correct?

Answer (score 2):

An edit to your data to give a case where both `put` and `call` does not exist (I changed the very last "call" to "put"):

```
x <- data.table(Tickers=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","D","D","D","D"),
            Type=c("put","call","put","call","call","put","call","put","call","put","put"),
            Strike=c(35,37.5,37.5,10,11,11,12,40,40,42,42),
            Other=sample(20,11))
```

Since you are using `data.table`, you can use the built in counter `.N` along with `by` variables to count groups and subset with that. If by counting `Type` you can reliably determine there is both `put` and `call`, this could work:

```
x[, `:=`(n = .N, types = uniqueN(Type)), by = c('Tickers', 'Strike')][n > 1 & types == 2]
```

The part enclosed in the first set of `[]` does the counting, and then the `[n > 1 & types == 2]` does the subsetting.

Comment: i like this solution! I will create sample data that is larger and more in line with the size of my full data and compare results soon!

Answer (score 0):

I am not a user of package `data.table` so this code is base R only.

```
agg <- aggregate(Type ~ Tickers + Strike, data = x, length)
result <- merge(x, subset(agg, Type > 1)[1:2], by = c("Tickers", "Strike"))[, c(1, 3, 2, 4)]
result
#   Tickers Type Strike Other
#1:       A call   37.5    17
#2:       A  put   37.5     7
#3:       B call   11.0    14
#4:       B  put   11.0    20
#5:       D  put   40.0    15
#6:       D call   40.0     2
#7:       D  put   42.0     8
#8:       D call   42.0     1


rm(agg)    # final clean up
```