# How to flag duplicate values in r - newbie

Tags: r, duplicates, flags

I'm trying to flag duplicate IDs in another column. I don't necessarily want to remove them yet, just create an indicator (0/1) of whether the IDs are unique or duplicates. In sql, it would be like this:

SELECT `ID`, count(`ID`) count from `TABLE` group by `ID`) a
On `TABLE`.`ID` = a.`ID`
set `ID Duplicate Flag Column 1` = 1 
where count > 1;

Is there a way to do this simply in r?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check `?duplicated`.

Comment: Like @RonakShah said. You can also use `table` and `rle`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding ALL duplicate rows, including "elements with smaller subscripts"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts)

Answer (score 1):

As an example of `duplicated` let's start with some values (numbers here, but strings would do the same thing)

```
x <- c(9, 1:5, 3:7, 0:8)
x
# 9 1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

If you want to flag the second and later copies

```
as.numeric(duplicated(x))
# 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

If you want to flag all values that occur two or more times

```
as.numeric(x %in% x[duplicated(x)])
# 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Ok, not really sure how to write that, or if that actually gives me what I'm looking for? I have nearly 1 million records and I just want to flag whether the 'unique' id is repeated (i.e., one column of data, not the entire row). I've tried the following, which I think gets me pretty close, but I get an error saying "replacement has xxx rows, data has xxx rows")

Comment: Data$DupeFlagColumn[!duplicated(Data$Column)] <- 0