# Set a variable to NA if other variables are duplicates in R

Tags: r, merge, duplicates, unique, na

I have the following data frame containing medicine code according to the route of administration:

```
code <- data.frame(inn = c("ibuprofen", "ibuprofen", "ibuprofen", "fusidic acid", "fusidic acid"),
                   route = c("unknown", "unknown", "unknown", "oral", "topical"),
                   atc = c("R02AX02", "G02CC01", "M01AE01", "J01XC01", "D06AX01"))

           inn   route     atc
1    ibuprofen unknown R02AX02
2    ibuprofen unknown G02CC01
3    ibuprofen unknown M01AE01
4 fusidic acid    oral J01XC01
5 fusidic acid topical D06AX01
```

And another one containing patient treatment and event:

```
event <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2),
                    inn = c("ibuprofen", "fusidic acid", "fusidic acid"),
                    route = c("unknown", "oral", "topical"),
                    event = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

  id          inn   route event
1  1    ibuprofen unknown  TRUE
2  1 fusidic acid    oral FALSE
3  2 fusidic acid topical  TRUE
```

I need to merge those data frames to get the following result:

```
           inn   route id event     atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE NA
```

I do not get this result with a simple `merge`:

```
merge(x = event,
      y = code)

           inn   route id event     atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE R02AX02
4    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE G02CC01
5    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE M01AE01
```

I thought of two solutions, but I did not manage to implement any:

- modify the `code` data frame before the `merge` to set `atc` to `NA` if there is different `atc` for a group of `inn` and `route` (this seems more appropriate)
- modify the result of `merge` to set `atc` to `NA` if there is different `atc` for a group of `inn`, `route` and `id`

How can I do it in base R? Is there another better way? I work in a restrictive environment where I only have access to base R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way to accomplish option 2. Starting with the result of a simple merge:

```
mrg <- merge(x = event,
             y = code)

           inn   route id event     atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE R02AX02
4    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE G02CC01
5    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE M01AE01
```

We then check which rows are duplicated (dropping the `atc` variable). We need to use duplicated twice because it actually finds *duplicate* rows, not rows that have duplicates. So, it would catch rows 4 and 5, but not 3 – to get that, we need to repeat `duplicated` from the opposite direction. Read more here: [Finding ALL duplicate rows, including “elements with smaller subscripts”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts):

```
mrg$atc <- ifelse(duplicated(mrg[,-5]) | duplicated(mrg[,-5], fromLast = T),
                  NA,
                  mrg$atc)
mrg

           inn   route id event     atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE    <NA>
4    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE    <NA>
5    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE    <NA>
```

If you want to get rid of the duplicate rows 4 and 5, just run `duplicated` one more time to drop them:

```
mrg[!duplicated(mrg),]

           inn   route id event     atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE    <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! This method is much quicker than the `ave` method. I applied the `ifelse` on `code[c("inn", "route")]` before the `merge` to merge smaller data frames to be more efficient and I used `unique(x = code)` instead of `code[!duplicated(x = code), ]` because it is more efficient according to the doc.

Answer (score 2):

The code for the case 2:

```
code$inn_route <- paste0(code$inn,'_',code$route)
code$count <- table(code$inn_route)[code$inn_route]
code[code$count>1,3]<-NA
code$inn_route <- NULL
code$count <- NULL
code <- unique(code)
merge(event,code)


           inn   route id event   atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE    <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your reasoning gave me an idea for a more straightforward way (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Grzegorz Sionkowski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55545034/11148823) led me to the following solution:

```
code$atc <- as.character(x = code$atc)

code$atc <- ifelse(test = ave(x = code$atc,
                              code$inn,
                              code$route,
                              FUN = length) > 1,
                   yes = NA,
                   no = code$atc)

code <- unique(x = code)

merge(x = event,
      y = code)

           inn   route id event     atc
1 fusidic acid    oral  1 FALSE J01XC01
2 fusidic acid topical  2  TRUE D06AX01
3    ibuprofen unknown  1  TRUE    <NA>
```

However, as `ave` is quite slow on my real data, I am wondering if there is a faster base R method.