# How to identify the rows with different values compare to other rows?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe in R

```
ID b  c  d  
1  33 33 35  
2  33 33 35  
3  32 34 36  
4  33 33 35  
5  32 33 35  
6  33 33 35
```

My desire is to find out the rows with different values compare to other rows. In this case, the rows with different values will be ID3 and ID5.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: You can negate the approach provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts) - `df[!(duplicated(df[2:4]) | duplicated(df[2:4], fromLast = TRUE)),]`.

Comment: Or a `dplyr` approach `df %>% group_by_at(2:4) %>% filter(n() == 1)` followed by an optional `ungroup()` if necessary.