# Separate all duplicate columns in R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

I have a question regarding indentifying and separating duplicate rows in R. I have, say a 2 column dataset, and in one of them I check for duplicates. If it finds any, I want to create a dataset with BOTH OF THE ROWS of a duplicate, so I can go and check the issues with them. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See if [this FAQ answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7854433/903061). Something like `result = your_data[duplicated(your_data$your_column) | duplicated(your_data$your_column, fromLast = TRUE), ]`.

Comment: If you have trouble or need more help, please post a reproducible sample of data in your question, preferably using `dput()` on an illustrative subset, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: My problem seems to be solved with the first comment, I just failed to add the second duplicated column to the result.