# How to create a dummy variable based on other columns values in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dummy-variable

I am cleaning a scraped dataset from duplicates. I want to create a dummy variable indicating whether I have two or more observations that are identical in all conditions or all conditions but one.

Here's an example of my dataset:

| Postcode | nrooms | price | sqm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 1 | 259 | 30 |
| 75 | 5 | 380 | 120 |
| 75 | 5 | 400 | 120 |
| 75 | 2 | 450 | 80 |
| 76 | 1 | 259 | 30 |

Here's the dummy I want:

| Postcode | nrooms | price | sqm | dummy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76 | 1 | 259 | 30 | 1 |
| 75 | 5 | 380 | 120 | 1 |
| 75 | 5 | 400 | 120 | 1 |
| 75 | 2 | 450 | 80 | 0 |
| 76 | 1 | 259 | 30 | 1 |

Where first and last rows have same values over all characteristics, the second and the third have same values in all characteristics but one (the price).

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this grouped by `postcode`?

Answer (score 0):

Using two `apply` calls and the `duplicated` function (see [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts)). We loop over all combinations of columns of size size ncol - 1, looking for duplicates using `duplicated`. Since you're looking for duplicates of all columns or all but one, we just need to look at combinations of size ncol - 1. Then we loop over the result of that operation to find out if any of the rows have duplicates for any of the column combinations.

```
apply(
  apply(combn(ncol(dat), ncol(dat) - 1),  
        2,
        FUN = function(cc) 
          duplicated(dat[,cc]) | duplicated(dat[,cc], fromLast = TRUE)),
  1, 
  max)

# [1] 1 1 1 0 1
```

As always, with a loop inside a loop, it can be helpful to step through each part of this. Inspecting output from `combn(ncol(dat), ncol(dat) - 1)` and then the inner `apply`