# How to make duplicated() show both duplicated values

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data.frame and I want to list *all* records which have duplicates in columns "bod" and "datum". There is a very nice function `duplicated`, unfortunatelly, it shows just one of the records:

```
visits2[duplicated(visits2[,c('bod','datum')]),]
```

Such handy function should be able to list all of the duplicates, shouldn't it? Or does R have a different handy function for that?

The only thing I was able to come up with is to call it twice like this, but that's pretty clumsy, so I consider it just a workaround:

```
visits2[duplicated(visits2[,c('bod','datum')]) | duplicated(visits2[,c('bod','datum')], fromLast = TRUE),]
```

I feel that for such a common task R deserves better solution than that! :-)

PS: please don't post answers writing "your own" functions for that... I know it can be done ;-) That's not the point. Perhaps the best thing would be to add a new option to `duplicated()`.

Comment: People have been scratching there heads about this before - some alternatives here: [Finding ALL duplicate rows, including “elements with smaller subscripts”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts)

Comment: If you want to show only duplicates, why not just drop the rows with unique values?

Comment: Another thread, but with the reverse question stackoverflow.com/q/35832931/10276092 maybe modified like: x[x$y %in% x[duplicated(x$y), "y"], ]

Comment: Thanks very much @Henrik! I see they came to the same workaround as I found. I'd like to push it a bit further :-)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "push it a bit further", otherwise the question may be considered a duplicate of the link I posted. Cheers

Comment: I already wrote it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here might be one workaround

```
subset(
  visits2,
  ave(1:nrow(visits2),
    interaction(visits2[, c("bod", "datum")]),
    FUN = length
  ) > 1
)
```