# New column to identify duplicate rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

Seeking some expertise/guidance on creating a new column to indicate possible duplicates based on a few selected columns.

I have the following dataframe

| ID | Animal | Age | Delivery | Cost | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | 5 | Air | 120 | Nigeria |
| 2 | cat | 3 | Air | 110 | Kenya |
| 3 | fish | 1 | Air | 20 | Kenya |
| 4 | dog | 5 | Air | 150 | Nigeria |
| 5 | cat | 3 | Air | 100 | Kenya |
| 6 | dog | 6 | Air | 180 | Egypt |
| 7 | cat | 3 | Air | 135 | Kenya |
| 8 | turtle | 10 | Air | 90 | Nigeria |

```
df = structure(list(ID = 1:8, Animals = c("dog", "cat", "fish", "dog", 
                                          "cat", "dog", "cat", "turtle"), Age = c(5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
                                           3L, 10L), Delivery = c("Air", "Air", "Air", "Air", "Air", "Air", 
                                           "Air", "Air"), Cost = c(120L, 110L, 20L, 150L, 100L, 180L, 135L, 
                                           90L), Country = c("Nigeria", "Kenya", "Kenya", "Nigeria", "Kenya", 
                                           "Egypt", "Kenya", "Nigeria")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                           -8L))
```

I would like to create a new column that highlights if the 3 columns - Animal, Age & Country repeats more than once to tag as duplicates.

The output would be the following

| ID | Animal | Age | Delivery | Cost | Country | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dog | 5 | Air | 120 | Nigeria | Y |
| 2 | cat | 3 | Air | 110 | Kenya | Y |
| 3 | fish | 1 | Air | 20 | Kenya | N |
| 4 | dog | 5 | Air | 150 | Nigeria | Y |
| 5 | cat | 3 | Air | 100 | Kenya | Y |
| 6 | dog | 6 | Air | 180 | Egypt | N |
| 7 | cat | 3 | Air | 135 | Kenya | Y |
| 8 | turtle | 10 | Air | 90 | Nigeria | N |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is essentially this r-FAQ - [Finding ALL duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts) - e.g.: `{function(x) duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)}(df[c("Animals","Age","Country")])` and the [tidyverse equivalent answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56632683/496803) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `group_by` your target columns, then use `n()` to see if there's more than one record per group.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Animals, Age, Country) %>% mutate(dup = n() > 1) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 × 7
     ID Animals   Age Delivery  Cost Country dup  
  <int> <chr>   <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>   <lgl>
1     1 dog         5 Air        120 Nigeria TRUE 
2     2 cat         3 Air        110 Kenya   TRUE 
3     3 fish        1 Air         20 Kenya   FALSE
4     4 dog         5 Air        150 Nigeria TRUE 
5     5 cat         3 Air        100 Kenya   TRUE 
6     6 dog         6 Air        180 Egypt   FALSE
7     7 cat         3 Air        135 Kenya   TRUE 
8     8 turtle     10 Air         90 Nigeria FALSE
```