# How to return all duplicated rows in R data.table?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, data.table

I have a R data.table with columns "itemNum", "Year", and "Amount". I used the following script, wanting to return items with the same amount in the same year. However, I'm only getting one of the duplicated rows. What's the right approach?

```
DT[duplicated(DT, by=c('Year', 'Amount'))==TRUE]
```

Comment: Use `DT[duplicated(DT, by=c('Year', 'Amount')) | duplicated(DT, by=c('Year', 'Amount'), fromLast = TRUE)]` (and you don't need the `== TRUE` part in your original code) - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854433/finding-all-duplicate-rows-including-elements-with-smaller-subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `mult` argument to find all duplicated rows

```
DT[duplicated(DT, by = c('Year', 'Amount'), mult = 'all') | duplicated(DT, by = c('Year', 'Amount'), fromLast = TRUE, mult = 'all')]
```

Comment: Does this add any additional value to simply: `DT[duplicated(DT, by=c('Year', 'Amount')) | duplicated(DT, by=c('Year', 'Amount'), fromLast = TRUE)]`, and if so, could you articulate that added value?

Comment: Can you help me find where `mult=` is defined? `data.table::duplicated` doesn't have an explicit `mult=`, and `...` says *"Not used at this time"*; `base::duplicated` might use `...` as *"arguments for particular methods"*, perhaps it's in there. I don't see any difference using `mult="all"` or `mult="nothing"` or any other value.